# Sign change during factorization polynomial

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

While trying to brush up on some basic calculus, I can’t understand where the positive sign (1+) comes from in the denominator.

[image]

Comment: It comes from $-\times -=+$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look at the denominator, and recall that $--$ becomes $+$.

Then $$4x-(-4x)\sqrt{1-\frac{3}{16x}}=4x+4x\sqrt{1-\frac{3}{16x}}\\
=(4x)\cdot 1+(4x)\cdot\sqrt{1-\frac{3}{16x}}=(4x) \cdot \left(1+\sqrt{1-\frac{3}{16x}}\right)$$

Now make $4x$ a common factor.

Comment: So actually, there is an implied, yet unwritten, 1 after the plus sign in the denominator?

Comment: @DarcNawg No. the one is actually coming from the FIRST 4x. $$4x=(4x) \cdot 1$$ Now make $4x$ a common factor.

Comment: @N With 4x as a common factor, wouldn’t you get 4x(1 + 1) instead of 4x(1+ ?

Comment: @DarcNawg $4x\sqrt{1-\frac{3}{16x}}$ means $(4x)\cdot\sqrt{1-\frac{3}{16x}}$.

Comment: can the downvoter explain what is wrong with this answer?

Answer (score -1):

The sign is in the denominator, not the numerator.  Here we are using the distributive law.  The $1$ comes from the $4x$ term and the $+$ comes from the two minus signs.